# Why is my serial number system repeating the number 001?

Tags: java, for-loop, serialization, linked-list

I'm trying to assign a unique ID to my contacts list in Java. It works fine except for the first number. It always repeats ID001 twice before moving on to ID002. Any Idea why?

```
private static String getSN() {
    String SN = "ID001";
    for (int i = 0; i < AddressBook.size(); i++) {
        if(AddressBook.size()<10){
        if (AddressBook.get(i).substring(0, 4).contains("ID00"+i));
        int snString = i+1;

        SN = "ID00"+Integer.toString(snString);

        if(SN.equals("ID0010")){
            SN = ("ID010");
        }
        }
        else{
            if(AddressBook.size()<100){
                if (AddressBook.get(i).substring(0, 5).equals("ID0"+i));
                int snString = i+1;
                SN = "ID0"+Integer.toString(snString);

                if(SN.equals("ID00100")){
                    SN = ("ID0100");
                }
                }

        }

    }
    return SN;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is my serial number system repeating the number 001?

Because `SN` is a local variable.  A local variable in a static method is still a local variable, and it disappears each time a call to the method returns.

You probably should be using a `static` field ... declared in the enclosing class.

Comment: Well why does it work after the first number then? I tried declaring the variable outside of the method and it still does the same thing.

Comment: Now that I look more closely, there is a whole lot more wrong with the code that just where `SN` is declared.  I suggest you start again, and make `SN` an integer.  When you need a new identifier, increment the integer and turn the integer into a string according to your formatting rules.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a much simpler way to do things. Instead of using a loop, every time I add a new person to my contact list I will ad a serial number.

```
private static void setSN() {
    if (AddressBook.size() < 10) {

        for (int i = 0; i < AddressBook.size(); i++) {

            String tempString = AddressBook.get(i);

            if (tempString.contains("ID00" + Integer.toString(AddressBook.size() + 1))) {
                SN = "ID00" + Integer.toString(AddressBook.size() + 2);
            }
            else{
                SN = "ID00" + Integer.toString(AddressBook.size() + 1);
        }

        }
    } 

    else {
        if (AddressBook.size() < 100) {
            for (int i = 0; i < AddressBook.size(); i++) {

                String tempString = AddressBook.get(i);

                if (tempString.contains("ID0" + Integer.toString(AddressBook.size() + 1))) {
                    SN = "ID0" + Integer.toString(AddressBook.size() + 2);

                }
                else{
                    SN = "ID0" + Integer.toString(AddressBook.size() + 1);
            }


        }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
1. Modify `AddressBook.get(i).substring(0, 4).contains("ID00"+i)` by
    `AddressBook.get(i).substring(0, 5).contains("ID00"+(i+1))`
2. Modify `int snString = i+1;`  by
 `int snString = i+2;`
3. This is because the index of the list starts at 0.

```
private static String getSN() {
    String SN = "ID001";
    for (int i = 0; i < AddressBook.size(); i++) {
        if(AddressBook.size()<10){
            if (AddressBook.get(i).substring(0, 5).contains("ID00"+(i+1))){
                int snString = i+2;
                SN = "ID00"+Integer.toString(snString);
            }
            if(SN.equals("ID0010")){
                SN = ("ID010");
            }
        } else {
            if(AddressBook.size()<100){
                if (AddressBook.get(i).substring(0, 5).equals("ID0"+(i+1))) {
                    int snString = i+2;
                    SN = "ID0"+Integer.toString(snString);
                }
                if(SN.equals("ID00100")){
                    SN = ("ID0100");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return SN;
}
```